# No cipher suites in common

Tags: restlet, dialogflow-es

I am trying to get Google Home / API.ai communicating with a simple Java server REST API coded with RESTlet

I have set up a self-signed developer certificate as the webhook communication requires using HTTPS

When the webhook tries to communicate with my server I am seeing an error which says SSHHandshakeException no cipher suites in common.

I have tried adding parameters to the Series and added the enabledCipherSuites parameter with a few cipher IDs I found online but I am unsure what cipher suites API.ai supports.

Is there a way to accept any requests ciphers so I get the communication between API.ai and my webhook working?

Comment: Please follow the recommended settings in [the SSL/TLS debugging guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) and check in the logs which cipher suites the client sending the `ClientHello` does understand. Note that most (if not all) TLSv1/1.1 ciphers are considered as unsafe and may get removed by your framework automatically

Comment: In the SSL debug it lists the unsupported cipher suites and then it has a section named Cipher Suites where it looks a lot of cipher suites.

Are these cipher suites the ones it is telling the client that it supports?

Comment: The client sends the cipher suites it supports within the `ClientHello` message to the server. The server will pick one that it understands or otherwise return a handshake server that no ciphers are in common (the error you got). Which SSL/TLS version are you trying to set up? As already mentioned, most of the TLSv1/1.1 ciphers are more or less unsafe and might get filtered by your backing framework. Also, which ciphers did you specify in your configuration? Maybe you try a TLSv1.2 connection but defined TLSv1/1.1 ciphers?

Comment: You can also try the services from [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/) to see what your server is actually capable of

Comment: I have no control over the client I have just provided the endpoint in the webhook section of API.ai, but I can see that in the ClientHello part it is mentioning TLSv1.2
I tried the ssllaabs service which queried my endpoint and it said "No secure protocols supported"
I suspect I have actually set up the self-signed certificate incorrectly as I found a few guides online and have tried a variety of ways using both the Java keystore app along with the openssl command

Comment: Maybe what I really need to understand here is how to create a valid key that will work with RESTlet that supports TLSv1.2 that the client is requesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from Google that you HAVE to used a SSL certificate from a trusted certificate authority and NOT a self-signed certificate, maybe one day API.AI will update their documentation to mention this